# PHP For loop to While loop conversion

Tags: php

simple question I hope, been stuck for hours so would appreciate some assistance.

I need to know how to convert this to a do while:

```
for ($counter = 0 ; $counter < 10 ; $counter++) {
```

and this to a while:

```
for ($mower = $counter ; $mower ; $mower--) {
```

Thanks for any help, and can offer more information if necessary

Comment: why does this seem like a homework exercise?

Comment: I've bought a book on how to learn PHP and at the end of each chapter there are exercises to complete. I've got the code working and displaying what it wants fine, but I'm unsure how to convert the loops from for.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn because in the real world, nobody *needs* to convert a `for` loop to a `do..while` loop.

Comment: I thought homework is ok to post no?

Comment: @fab If the for loop does what it's supposed to, why would anyone *need* to convert it? **Edit**: You were answering his question and weren't being sarcastic - disregard my stupidity. :)

Comment: @span, yes, however, Thou shalt not help those that can not help themselves ^.^

Comment: Thank you for the useful replies guys, but to repeat, this is an exercise from a book I'm using on how to learn PHP and not a homework problem.

Comment: @user2187585 It it is still kind of a homework problem, just because you didn't get it from a teacher at a school doesn't mean you shouldn't try and solve it yourself. The problem is that your question doesn't show any research effort, i.e. [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 3):

```
for (init; condition; increment) {
    stuff; 
}
```

is nearly exactly equivalent to

```
init;
while (condition) {
    stuff;
    increment;
}
```

(in most cases even compiling to the same byte sequences), in nearly all languages with C-like syntax (including PHP).

It's also similar to

```
init;
if (condition) do {
    stuff;
    increment;
} while (condition);
```

with the exception that the latter is hideous.  :)  Note, though, if the initial state and condition are such that you know the first iteration will always run, you can get rid of the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, something like this?

```
$counter = 0;
do {
  $counter++;
} while($counter < 10);

$mower = $counter;
while($mower) {
  $mower--;
}
```

Comment: in first, OP want with do while loop.

Comment: Yeah. True. It might be the same but he wants a do while :)

Comment: Ahaa! I thought it was weird that everyone were doing do whiles. Will edit!

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;
do {
    // Do things
    $counter ++;
} while ($counter  < 10);
```

and

```
$mower = $counter;
while ($mower) {
    // Do things
    $mower--;
}
```

More info:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: Burnt by @span for 3 seconds :D

Answer (score 0):

First one:

```
$cont = 0;
do{
   //whatever
   $cont++;
}while($cont<10);
```

Second:

```
$mover = $counter;
while($mower){
    //whatever
   $mower--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First do while loop:

```
$counter = 0;

do{

// some statement
$counter ++;
} while($counter < 10);
```

For while loop:

```
$mower = $counter; 
while($mower){
   //statement
$mower--;
}
```